# Can i disabled back button in my browser only for 1 page in asp-mvc4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my javascript to make the page auto direct to lockscreen when there is no user activity,but in the lock screen,we can click back button and access the account without enter the password to unlock the lockscreen

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onkeypress = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        alert("Time expired!");
        document.location.href = "logout.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do some validation on your server and you won't have this issue.

Comment: how can i make the validation ?                                  can you give me example sir ?

Comment: Use form authentication.. Where everytime page loads it will check whether user are authenticated or not and then it will only allow the to render page.

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware, you cannot disable the back button only create a solution that works around it.

Comment: **You should not just rely on JavaScript for security!** You need to add some form of authentication to your web pages. These are supplied as part of ASP.Net MVC 4. Suggest you research them.